# R: put the table from "htmlTable" in the middle of the page (html report)

Tags: r, html-table, datatable, r-markdown, report

I'm struggling to find a way to **place my table in the middle of the page in my R markdown** using "getDescriptionStatsBy" and "htmlTable" functions

```
library(Gmisc);library(htmlTable)

tables%>% 
    Gmisc::getDescriptionStatsBy(Age,sexe,by=Group,
                          statistics = list(continuous = getPvalAnova, 
                                          factor = getPvalChiSq, 
                                          proportion = getPvalFisher),
                           factor_fn = describeFactors,header_count = "n=%s",show_all_values=T,html = T)%>% 
   htmlTable::addHtmlTableStyle(align='c')%>% 
   htmlTable::htmlTable(caption  = "Demographic Table")
```

**html report preview:**
[image]

I tried with the argument "`align='c'`" in `addHtmlTableStyle` function, but it doesn't work, the table is still in left side of the htlm report.. Any ideas ?! thanks

### ***** ANSWER *****

I found a solution :
I just needed to add before the chunk `<div align="center">` and `</div>` after

````
<div align="center">
```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.align = 'center', fig.width = 6, fig.height = 4, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}

tables%>%
    Gmisc::getDescriptionStatsBy(Age,sexe,by=Group,
                          statistics = list(continuous = getPvalAnova,
                                          factor = getPvalChiSq,
                                          proportion = getPvalFisher),
                           factor_fn = describeFactors,header_count = "n=%s",show_all_values=T,html = T)%>%
    htmlTable::addHtmlTableStyle(align='c')%>%
    htmlTable::htmlTable(caption  = "Demographic Table")
```
</div>
````